# probability that a blue ball is taken out before any red ones

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A box contains 1 blue, 2 red and 3 green balls. Balls are taken out at
random with replacement and the colours of the balls are recorded. What is the probability
that a blue ball is taken out before any red ones?

Here's how I tackled this problem:

We have 20 times out of 60 permutations that the blue ball is places before the 2 red ones:

Here's how I calculated it:

when blue ball is on 1st position we have 5!/3!2!=10 ways of placing the green and red balls between themselves, then we do it for blue ball on 2nd,3rd,4th, with 6,3,1 ways respectively. We have 6!/3!2! total permutations of the 6 balls. So P(blue before red)= (10+6+3+1)/60=1/3 .

Is this the correct way to do it? Could you please hint what is not right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conclusion is certainly correct.

A simpler way to see it:  we don't care about the green balls at all.  We are only interested in the three balls, $B, R_1, R_2$.  One of these three must be drawn before the others, so by symmetry the answer is $\frac 13$.

Comment: Thanks. But why wouldn't we care about the green balls?

Comment: The greens are irrelevant... you could have 100 greens in a row and it affects nothing.  *One* position will be the first non-green.  There is a $1/3$ chance it is blue, $2/3$ chance it is red.  That's all that matters.  Wait long enough and you're certain (in probability) to get the "other" color.

Comment: @lulu I assume it's a small typo that you labeled the three balls as $G,R_1,R_2$ since the first one perhaps should be labeled $B$ instead to stand for Blue?

Comment: @JohnOmielan  Absolutely.  Thanks, will correct.